# golang cannot assign interface {} for struct

Tags: go

Hello Expert I'm using this libraray to store K/V in cache

`"github.com/bluele/gcache"`

The value which I store is this Data Structure

```golang
type LatestBlockhashCacheResult struct {
    Blockhash            string `json:"blockhash"`
    LastValidBlockHeight uint64 `json:"lastValidBlockHeight"` // Slot.
    CommitmentType  string `json:"commitmentType"`
}
```

```golang
lbhr := LatestBlockhashCacheResult{
            Blockhash:            lbh.Value.Blockhash.String(),
            LastValidBlockHeight: lbh.Value.LastValidBlockHeight,
            CommitmentType:       string(commitmentType),
        }
        gc.SetWithExpire(lbh.Value.LastValidBlockHeight, lbhr, time.Hour*10)
```

I have no problem with retrieving the cache but not able to Typecast it

```golang
c, _ := gc.Get(rf.LastValidBlockHeight)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", c)
```

So when i Try this

```
var c = LatestBlockhashCacheResult{}
    c, _ = gc.Get(rf.LastValidBlockHeight)
```

This throws me error

`cannot assign interface {} to c (type LatestBlockhashCacheResult) in multiple assignment: need type assertion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign `interface{}` to a typed variable.
In order to do this you need first try to cast the `interface{}` value to a specific type

```
val, err := gc.Get(rf.LastValidBlockHeight)
if err != nil {
  // handle 
}

c, ok := val.(LatestBlockhashCacheResult)
if !ok {
   // val has different type than LatestBlockhashCacheResult
}
```

Refs: 
https://go.dev/tour/methods/15 
https://go.dev/tour/methods/16